# How do I check if a date has consecutive rows in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

This is my dataframe,

```
date            id        name           score

2020-10-19      1         Peter          0
2020-10-19      2         Betty          50
2020-10-19      3         Susie          45
2020-10-18      1         Peter          0
2020-10-18      2         Betty          50
2020-10-18      3         Susie          45
2020-10-17      1         Peter          60
2020-10-17      2         Betty          0
2020-10-17      3         Susie          45
```

How can I check if there was a score of 0 on two consecutive days? The following
table should be returned. (Betty did not have 0 on two consecutive dates)

```
date            id        name           score

2020-10-19      1         Peter          0
2020-10-18      1         Peter          0
```

I have tried:

```
df['score'] = (df.score.diff(1) == 0).astype('int').cumsum()
```

Note: the datetimes are always sorted in descending order.

Comment: you can get unique list of dates (`date_list`), and then get part of dataframe iterating over the `date_list`, sort by index and then do the shift comparison

Comment: There are sorted consecutive datetimes in input data?

Answer (score 1):

If datetimes are sorted you can test if 2 consecutive values per groups are `0`:

```
m1 = df['score'].eq(0) & df.groupby('id')['score'].shift(-1).eq(0)
m2 = df['score'].eq(0) & df.groupby('id')['score'].shift().eq(0)

df = df[m1 | m2]
print (df)
        date  id   name  score
0 2020-10-19   1  Peter      0
3 2020-10-18   1  Peter      0
```

Comment: Yes the datetimes will always be sorted.